# SCCM 2012 | Collection does not list the member added Directly

Tags: sccm, sccm-2012, sccm-2012-r2

In the Morning in SCCM 2012, I observed HourGlass on the collection after adding members for almost 3 hours. The collection was not updating. I removed the members and deleted the collection.

I have directly added two active computers to collection (Right Click on collection + Add Resources), with the limited to "all systems".

Now it is 2 hours and the two machines do not show up when double clicked on the collection.

When i check "Collection Properties > Membership Rules" I am able to see the two machines which i added with Type "Direct". But when i double click on the collection it does not show anything.

Any deployment i have done on this collection has not reached the machine. I have deleted and recreated the collection and same issue.  I have added these machine from CAS (CAS + Primary Concept).

Comment: Do these two workstations appear within the 'All Systems' collection which is being used as the limiting collection? It may be worth doing a update collection on the all systems and then another update collection on the new one you've just created.

Comment: @JoeS these workstations are listed under all system. I suspect some replication issue, but under site replication i see no errors. I shall update collection and get back to u..

Comment: Hey @JohnFranky, did you manage to try forcing an update on the collection?

Comment: @JoeS Yes, i updated the all systems. Had the same issue. I rebooted the VM of primary server and after 2hrs of sync and update collection.. Worked !! Now all is fine. thank you for support.